# Issue understanding scipy.integrate.RK45 requirements

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I am attempting to solve a system of first order differential equations with `scipy.integrate.RK45()`. I have scripted out the model function that I am hoping to plot (displacement vs time), but `RK45()` requires that this function takes 2 arguments, namely 't' and 'y', where 't' is a scalar and 'y' is an array in my case. This is better described below:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html

My script is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import RK45, RK23

def model(t, y):
    
    m = 2
    c = 10
    k = 1500

    if (t >= 0 and t < 0.1):
        F = 200 * t
    if (t >= 0.1 and t < 0.25):
        F = 20
    else:
        F = 0
    
    E_matrix = [[0, 1], [(-k / m), (-c / m)]]
    Q_matrix = [0, F / m]

    return E_matrix * X + Q_matrix

time_step = 0.01
t_upper = 0.5
t_lower = 0

initial_conditions = [0, 0]

points_to_plot = RK45(fun=model(t, y), t0=t_lower, y0=initial_conditions, t_bound=t_upper, vectorized=True)
```

A picture of the system I'd like to solve is seen below:
[image: System of DEs]

I have found very few examples of this being used as most solutions use `odeint()`.

**What are these two arguments (t, y) and how would I effectively incorporate them into my function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `t` already. Now, change `def model(t, y):` to `def model(t, X):` and you will use `X` as well. Note that t and y are positional arguments, you can call them however you like in your function. You have another issue, which is that you multiply Python lists! In Python, as opposed to Matlab, you need to specify that you make an array:

Change

```
E_matrix = [[0, 1], [(-k / m), (-c / m)]]
Q_matrix = [0, F / m]
```

to

```
E_matrix = np.array([[0, 1], [(-k / m), (-c / m)]])
Q_matrix = np.array([0, F / m])
```

and

```
return E_matrix*X + Q_matrix
```

to

```
return E_matrix @ X + Q_matrix
```

as `@` is the matrix product in NumPy. `*` performs element-wise product.

EDIT: I hadn't spotted the call `RK45(fun=model(t, y),`. By doing that, you are passing the value of the function model at `t,y`. You need to give the function itself: `RK45(fun=model, ...`

Comment: Hi Pierre, thank you very much for the help! I have made the relevant changes, but am now getting an error ```NameError: name 't' is not defined``` (which I also got previously). When calling the RK45 function, what should be assigned to t and X? Right now I just have ```RK45(fun=model(t, X)...``` as a place holder.

Comment: I hadn't spotted the `RK45(fun=model(t, y),`. By doing that, you are passing the value of the function `model` at `t,y`. You need to give the function itself: `RK45(fun=model, ...`